# How can get ListView object in setOnClickListener?

Tags: android

In Code 2, I use final ListView lv=this.getListView() to get ListView object, it's OK.

In Code 1, I try to use ListView lv=((ListActivity)getApplicationContext()).getListView() to get ListView object, but it's bad.

Is there a simple way to get get ListView object in setOnClickListener? Thanks

**Code 1**

```
private void IniControl(){  

        findViewById(R.id.btnCancel).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                                ListView lv=((ListActivity)getApplicationContext()).getListView();      
                for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++){
                       EditText number = (EditText)lv.findViewWithTag("editNumber"+i);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number.getText().toString()+"CW",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });         
    }
```

**Code 2**

```
public class StepList extends ListActivity{

    private ListNumberAdapter mListNumberAdapter=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sms_step_list);

    }


    private void IniControl(){

        final ListView lv=this.getListView(); 

        findViewById(R.id.btnCancel).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                for(int i=0;i<lv.getCount();i++){
                       EditText number = (EditText)lv.findViewWithTag("editNumber"+i);
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),number.getText().toString()+"CW",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });         
    }

}
```

Comment: where is `IniControl()` called?

Comment: I am confused. Are you trying to get the selected item that was clicked in the list view? Can you explain what your trying to do a little more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `IniControl` also a method of `StepList` in your Code 1 ?

If so, you can simply call `getListView()` from there (the `OnClickListener` being an inner class of your `StepList`), or more explicitely `StepList.this.getListView()`.

Comment: Thanks! but I don't unstand why ListView lv=((ListActivity)getApplicationContext()).getListView() in code 1  cause app crash?

Comment: The `Context` isn't the `Activity` itself, but rather a bunch of information about the environment the code is running in. It doesn't hold the `Activity`-related methods and data.

Comment: Thanks! do you mean sometimes it work and somtimes it don't work?

Comment: An `Activity` is always a `Context`, but a `Context` is not necessarily an `Activity`. In this case (getting the `Context` using `getApplicationContext()`), it's not, so what you did first will never work. If you haven't already, read a tutorial or a course about Inheritance and Polymorphim in Java, it will help you a lot :) Don't forget to mark the answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

The ListView is not a member of the ApplicationContext. Why cant you add the ListView as a member of the Activity instead? Or use the getListView() on the ListActivity's context.

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate `OnClickListener`  method and pass `ListView` to it.

```
private View.OnClickListener onClick(final ListView lv) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onListItemClick Method

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hoohoo..you clicked me at " + position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

It will display the the row number you clicked

Answer (score 0):

Make your ListView a class member Variable

```
 private ListView mListView;
```

Then in `onCreate()`, call `mListView = (ListView) this.getListView();`

And then you can use the `mListView` object anywhere in the rest of the code.